# Install Opera browser on Debian GNU/Linux 10 without sudo

Tags: debian, opera

I would like to know how to install the Opera browser on Linux without using the `sudo` command.

In the past I have been able to install `screen` and `gecko-driver` without using `sudo` by installing them on my personal user `bin` directory and then altering my `.bashrc` file appropriately, but I cannot figure out how to do the same for Opera.

I have tried installing it without `sudo` via `dpkg -x <opera_package> <user_bin_directory>`, but I get the error `libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` whenever I then try to run `opera` in the terminal.

Please note I have very little experience with Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the Opera package depends on the libffmpeg package, which is not installed... And probably cannot be installed without root access, as it would install to `/usr/lib`. You will most likely need to build both packages _from source_ instead of from a .deb file, so you can build them with your local user-specific directories. If you do have root access, you can install all the dependencies required by Opera,  and then your local user specific install should work.